# .htaccess redirection in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have the following rule in my .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.)?annsenglishmediumschool.com$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?(.*).annsenglishmediumschool.com$ [NC]    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/shops   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.annsenglishmediumschool.com/index.php/shops/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?annsenglishmediumschool.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

and this shows in my wildcard redirect in cpanel :

```
Domain : (www.)?(.*).annsenglishmediumschool.com
```

and `Redirect Url : www.annsenglishmediumschool.com/index.php/shops/` .  What i need is when user types `shops.annsenglishmediumschool.com` it should redirect to `annsenglishmediumschool.com/shops`.How to modify .htaccess according to this , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} shops.annsenglishmediumschool.com
RewriteRule .* http://annsenglishmediumschool.com/shops [L]
```

Just add that into your .htaccess file before `</IfModule>`

Comment: This works fine ! , but how to do this if "shops" is a variable here ?

Comment: What do you mean by if it's a variable? :S